# how to display the content of a folder using the folder name, not the path?

Tags: ruby

```
Dir.entries("folder path works but i need to use the folder name")
Dir.entries("folder path works but i need to use the folder name").select { |file| File.directory? File.join("folder path", file)}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand; how would just a name fully-qualify the directory? In other words, you need to know the location of the folder.

Comment: folder name works if you `Dir.chdir` to the respective parent directory first.